# Is Encrypted Sql Data secured when being transmitted from Server to Server

Tags: php, mysql, web-applications, server, client

If  run a Web application on a web server in one location and inside my php code I use OpenSSL to encrypt data, will the data be secured when transmitted to my SQL Server on my Server.

I am working on a Web application but it is being hosted on 3rd Party Web hosting Service but User Data is being Stored in SQL On my Personal Server. All Data will be encrypted Using OpenSSL on the web Server where web Server ask for the Users personal encryption key stored SQL One Time Per Session. I plan on Using a Second OpenSSL Encyption to Encrypt the User Encryption Keys. Users will also only be able to use the app via a Secured HTTPS Connection to Web Server.

I Just want to find out What I need to do to ensure User Data will be Secured to the Best of My Ablilities form mainly Man In Middle Attacks.

The Web Hosting Service is a Well Know Service with Secured Connections, I Will Have an upgraded SSL Certificate.

My SQL Server Will Only Except Connection from Web Server IP on a Non Standard SQL Port.

Comment: Encrypt your data with OpenSSL(I prefer Libsodium) at the application level before putting it on the DB and then decrypt your data at the application level.  You can then use RSA encryption to handle key exchanges between your users and the application.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have the front-end encryption taken care of, but what you are asking about is the connection to the back-end, or your SQL server. You need to make sure that you are properly defining a secure connection as that is the default, BUT MySQL will drop down to an unsecured connection if there are any issues in that config (past auth, of course).

Here is a link to the MySQL doc page, https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/encrypted-connections.html

You should be able to get some info there more specific to how you are trying to configure your connection string and user account.

-Tango